# jQuery get all items that is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this example:

HTML

```
<div id="Contents">
  <div id="Showing"></div>
  <div id="Hiding"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Hiding{
  display : none
}
```

Is there a way in jQuery that we can get all items in the DOM that is visible (display != none)? In this case, we get 2 divs that has id of 'Contents' and 'Showing'. Thank you very much.

Comment: `$('*').filter(':visible')`? Looking at your posted HTML and (invalid) CSS: what results would you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `:visible` selector

```js
$('*:visible').addClass('visible');
```

```css
#Hiding {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Contents">
  <div id="Showing">showing</div>
  <div id="Hiding">hiding</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case someone wants more information - https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Please excuse the edit, it's just that `:visible()` implies a method (despite the use of `:`), whereas `:visible` is a selector.

Comment: Thank you very much. Because in the API they only talk about visibility and opacity (and not about display) so I asked the question.

Comment: I could barely understand what OP is asking for, the same with your answer. What exactly did you change?

Comment: @Kinduser they want to use jquery to find all elements on the page that are visible. So I wrote a jquery line to target visible elements. What part don't you understand?

Comment: @LanMai no problem :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker Is fine, ekm. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

try this , here you will get only visible means display!=none items from Contents container.

HTML

```
<div id="Contents">
  <div id="Showing"></div>
  <div id="Hiding"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$("#Contents").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("visible")){
    $(this).show();
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  };
</script>
```

if you can try to get all hidden items of Contents using same code with hidden attributes.

```
<script>
    $("#Contents").each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("hidden")){
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) Have a nice day bro :)

Comment: It’s my pleasure :)